# Llamando a un método POST desde C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xamarin, asp.net-web-api

Tengo una API MVC con este método en mi controlador:

```
[HttpPost]
public void InsertSomething([FromBody] string test, [FromBody] List<MyClass> newList)
{
    ...
}
```

Y la quiero llamar desde C# pero no sé como. Estoy usando Xamarin Android.

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
List<MyClass> newList = getList();

string url = "http://localhost:57750/api/ControllerName/InsertSomething";
var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newList),Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
var result = client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

El problema es que no se está llamando al método del controlador, además, no se como agregar el otro parámetro tipo string que se llama test.

¿Alguna idea?

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web api no soporta todavia el bindeo de multiples parametros. Para que te funcione tienes que crear una clase con los nombres de los parametro que se envia en el body del request:

```
public class ParametrosInsert
{
   public string Test { get; set;}
   public List<MyClass> newList { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public void InsertSomething([FromBody] ParametrosInsert para)
{
   String test = para.Test;
    ...
}
```

Osea, simplemente encierra los parametros en una clase y espeficia que esa clase es la que esperas como parametro y web api se encargara de llenar la clase con sus respectivas propiedades.

Comment: No me funciona. Inclusive dejando los parámetros de mi controlador con parámetros tipo string no logra llamar al método :/

Comment: Te lanza algun error? Pudieras decirnos el StatusCode del response?

Comment: No, no lanza error. Se queda esperando al método y al parecer no lo encuentra nunca. Ni siquiera exception me tira. Tengo la API en modo debug y tampoco entra ahí D:

Comment: Intenta agregando Post al inicio del nombre del metodo `PostInsertSomething` solo para despejar dudas

Comment: Si no entra al método ¿es posible que la url `http://localhost:57750/api/ControllerName/...` sea incorrecta?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave pensé lo mismo, pero la llamo desde postman y si ejecuta el método :/

Comment: @Einer tampoco funcionó
Help :(

Comment: @GonzaloBustamante, encierra tu código en un `try/catch` y coloca un punto de interrupción en la primera línea de código de tu método. Intenta de nuevo invocar al método y, cuando llegue al punto de interrupción, presiona F10 para mirar en cada línea el flujo del programa. También intentaría comentar tu código y hacer que el método devuelva un Hola Mundo o un texto de prueba - solo para descartar algún problema con tu código...

Comment: Mira la actualizacion de mi respuesta.

Comment: Me funcionó. Muchas gracias!